# How to null check in EL to show p:dialogs conditionally?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, el

I have two `<p:dailog>`s and based on the condition of a bean property I want to show one of them. I have used the following code

```
onclick="#{empty groupBean.selectionGroup?dialog_empty.show():groupDialog.show()}"
```

But it is not working as it says there is an error in EL expression. I am not sure where the error is. Am I doing it the correct way?

Comment: In this particular case, the error happens to be obvious enough to be spotted by just looking at the code, but in the future questions about errors, you should **really** copypaste the *entire* error message as they usually already contains the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're treating JavaScript code as part of the EL expression. This would only result in a syntax error because EL cannot find `#{dialog_empty}` nor `#{groupDialog}` in the scope. You have to treat JavaScript code as strings by quoting them because they ultimately needs to be written to the HTML response as-is:

```
onclick="#{empty groupBean.selectionGroup ? 'dialog_empty.show()' : 'groupDialog.show()'}"
```

Comment: thanks BalusC. Actually there was no error in the console. Application also worked fine except this button. How can I enable the viewing of errors.

Comment: You said yourself "it says there is an error in EL expression"? So there's "an error". Or was that all what you got?

Comment: thts all I got. The application ran fine. No exceptions.

Comment: even now i can see a warning so that is why I ignored it. Following is the warning  `Description Resource Path Location Type
This empty expression always evaluates to false.  Only string, maps, arrays and collection have meaningful values for the empty operator group_detail.xhtml /mint_v1/WebContent/pages line 36 Facelet Validator`

Comment: Ah well, that must have been an ajax request. Perhaps PrimeFaces is suppressing it. Sorry, I don't use PrimeFaces extensively, I can't go in detail as to configuring it. At least, your concrete problem is now solved, right? :)